# Why can't I grid a bitmap image or photo image tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have this code, which uses the tkinter bitmap image:

```
def ask(msg='Question?',title='Question'):
    root=Tk()
    thing=Thing()
    root.title(title)
    imgw=BitmapImage(root,file='Question.xbm')
    root.iconbitmap('Question.ico')
    imgw.grid(rowspan=2,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=NSEW)
    msgw=Label(root,text=msg)
    msgw.grid(column=1,padx=10,pady=5,sticky=NSEW,columnspan=2)
    button1=Button(root,text='Yes',command=lambda:thing.change('Yes',root),underline=0)
    button1.grid(column=1,row=1,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=NSEW)
    button1.focus_set()
    button2=Button(root,text='No',command=lambda:thing.change('No',root),underline=0)
    button2.grid(column=2,row=1,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=NSEW)
    root.bind('Key-y',lambda:thing.change('Yes',root))
    root.bind('Key-n',lambda:thing.change('No',root))
    root.mainloop()
ask()
```

...but I can't grid the bitmap image. I've tried poth photo image and bitmap image but they both say:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\gui.py", line 18, in <module>
ask()
File "E:\gui.py", line 7, in ask
imgw.grid(rowspan=2,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=NSEW)
AttributeError: 'BitmapImage' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

I am using Python 3.4.2. Is there a way of doing this or is it just an annoying thing in tkinter?

By the way, here is the `Thing` class:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self,val=None):
        self.val=val
    def change(self,val=None,win=None):
        self.val=val
        if win:win.destroy()
```

Comment: AFAIK, `BitmapImage` is not a widget, like a Label, but a canvas object, i.e. you have to add it to a canvas, or maybe a label, and then layout that element.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [`BitmapImage`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/images.html) is not a widget, like a `Label` or a `Button`. It can not be added directly to `root` and laid out with `grid`. Instead, you have to add it to, e.g., another `Label` (or the same `Label` you use for the question, if you prefer).

```
root=Tk()

imgw = BitmapImage(file='Question.xbm')            # no 'root' parameter
imgLabel = Label(root,image=imgw)                  # wrap the BitmapImage
imgLabel.grid(rowspan=2,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=NSEW) # layout the label

msgw=Label(root,text="Question")
msgw.grid(column=1,padx=10,pady=5,sticky=NSEW,columnspan=2)
button1=Button(root,text='Yes')
button1.grid(column=1,row=1,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=NSEW)
button2=Button(root,text='No')
button2.grid(column=2,row=1,padx=5,pady=5,sticky=NSEW)
root.mainloop()
```

Also note that images like this tend to be garbage collected even when used in a Label. To prevent this, you should make the `BitmapImage` a global variable, or put it into a global container, e.g. a `dict` mapping filenames to already loaded images.

Comment: One addition to the garbage collection problem: you can add the `BitmapImage` variable to the label using (in this example) `imgLabel.image = imgw`. This makes sure the image is not garbage collected as long as the label isn't.